# Using Dynamic Range in Excel without using Named Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro which will run for the entire length of a worksheet and do the calculations accordingly.

This is the code I had for the static Range:

```
With .Range("P2:P" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=SUMIF('Sheet2'!A$2:A$530,'Sheet1'!N2,'Sheet2'!B$2:B$530)"
    .Value = .Value
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
End With
```

I have a basic idea of what I'm trying to do here but because I am new to VBA I can't really figure out how to do it.

This is the current code I'm Trying to Write:

```
 With .Range("P2:P" & LastRow)
        .Formula = "=SUMIF(Worksheets('Sheet2').Range("A2:A"& LR),'Sheet1'!N2,'Sheet2'!B$2:B$530)"
        .Value = .Value
        Columns("P:P").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With
```

However, for this it keeps on giving me an end of statement error, which I want to fix.

Also, LastRow and LR contain the last cell number of both the sheets respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Your syntax was a little off in the first bit of your SUMIF, and you were hardcoding the final row number. Note too there is no need to select.

```
With .Range("P2:P" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=SUMIF(Sheet2!A$2:A$" & LR & ",'Sheet1'!N2,'Sheet2'!B$2:B" & LR & ")"
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
End With
```

Comment: Good job on removing the SELECT - you can probably also remove  `.Value = .Value` - that doesn't seem to be doing much

Comment: @dbmitch - that replaces the actual formulae with their results (i.e. equivalent to copy/pastespecial values only).